# "update by query" not working as expected with straight calls

Tags: elasticsearch

I've an script that calls Elasticsearch with some `update_by_query`.

Here I update the item with `id=299966` and change the trash flag, `trash=0`:

```
_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "_id": [
                299966
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": [

        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.trash=0"
  }
}
```

Then I the item with `id=299966` (same item as above) to `trash=1`:

```
_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "_id": [
                299966
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": [

        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.trash=1"
  }
}
```

The thing is that after doing this two operations, if I search for the item with `id=299966`, I get `trash=0`, when it's supposed to be `trash=1` as it's the last one executed. I always mantain the order and my own log shows that the one with `trash=0` is first executed, and then the one with `trash=1`.

Is there any stuff inside the `update_by_query` logic that avoids to make two calls? Do I have to wait some seconds or something to make the second update_by_query?

PS: Nervemind those double `query` on the codes. It's working ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The endpoint is called `_update_by_query` not `update_by_query`, can you confirm you're using the correct one? And which version of ES do you have?

Comment: Yes I'm using the correct one. I'm using ES 2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is to use `_flush` after every `_update` or every `_update_by_query`.

```
myindex/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "_id": [
                299966
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": [

        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.trash=0"
  }
}

myindex/_flush

myindex/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "_id": [
                299966
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": [

        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.trash=1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why we need to flush after every update or update by query. Because it is never mentioned in the elasticsearch documentation.

Comment: The flush process of an index makes sure that any data that is currently only persisted in the transaction log is also permanently persisted in Lucene. So after the first `_update_by_query`, when you `_flush` you permanently save the data, and then you can make the second `_update_by_query` with no problem.

Comment: What happens when we don't use _flush? Anyway it will be eventually flushed right?

Comment: If you dont use `_flush` in the example above and you run two operation quite in the same time, everything could mess as stated on the post.